# How do I call an executable as if it were called from another folder?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a program `food` in `/bin/` that creates the file `dinner.txt` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch dinner.txt
```

I want to use my `food` program to create `dinner.txt` in my `/home/` folder without calling `cd /home/` first. In other words, I want to call `food` as if it were called from `/home/`. How would I do this?

**Edit:** Assume I can't edit the actual `food` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(cd ~ && /bin/food)`

This launches it in a subshell.

Comment: This is the most succinct command given that does what I want. Are there any gotchas I should be aware of when running processes in a subshell?

Comment: None I can think of off-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Assuming you can't change the code of the program, you can write a short wrapper script which will `export` `food.sh` as a global variable and then will execute it.

And, if you want to completely remove directory dependency from this script you can also export the wrapper script. This will allow you to run the script from any path in this `shell` session and always get the output file under `/home/`

Wrapper script `wrapper_food.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export mkfood="/home/shadowme/mkfood.sh"
cd /home/shadowe/testdir/
$mkfood
```

Output:

```
$ ls testdir
food.0.txt
```

Export of wrapper script:

```
$ export wrapper_food=/home/shadowe/wrapperfood.sh
```

Then you can call the script above from anywhere in the same shell:

```
$ $wrapper_food
```

Original Answer:

Generally speaking three ways come to mind to avoid `cd /home/` before `touch`:

1. Invoke `touch` with the full directory path of where to create `food.txt`
2. Store the directory path as a variable and then combine it in `touch`
3. Pass the directory path as an argument when invoking `sh` script.

One can choose each of the above depending on the use case. For example, if I'd like to always create files in the same directory I'll not use the argument option because it's longer input. Instead, I'll store the path as a variable.

The script below provides example for each of the above in the order they are mentioned.

Input:

```
$ ./mkfood.sh /home/shadowe/testdir
```

Output:

```
$ ls /home/shadowe/testdir
food1.txt  food2.txt  food.txt
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# store path as variable
dir_path="/home/shadowe/testdir"
touch $dir_path/food.txt

#direct path
touch /home/shadowe/testdir/food1.txt

# argument pass
touch $1/food2.txt
```

Lastly, even though it wasn't asked, it's possible to pass the file name to be created as an argument as well by changing the argument command to `touch $1/$2`. For example:

```
$ ./mkfood.sh /home/shadowe/testdir food2.txt
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my original question, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without modifying the original script, and instead using some bash command.

Comment: @HatTricks thank you for the clarification, I edited my answer in case you are allowed to write a short wrapper script.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is maybe. There are three possibilities that I can think of.

1) The food program has an option that allows the output file to be specified. The convention is usually (but not always) a `-o outputfile` option. Running a `man food` or trying `/bin/food -h` perhaps might show what options are available.

2) The food program has an option to write to `SDTOUT`. If that is the case, then you could run `/bin/food <whatever option writes to STDOUT> > /home/dinner.txt`.

3) Move the dinner.txt file after the `food` program is run. E.g. `food; mv dinner.txt /home`.

It would be helpful to know why you don't want to run `cd`. Running `cd /home; food; cd -` would run the program from `home` and change the directory back to what it was before the `food` command was run.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit the `food` program but can you write a new `eats` program?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "${@}"
food
```

can you

```
sudo mv /bin/food /bin/oldfood
sudo mv /bin/eats /bin/food
```

and change the /bin/food to call oldfood